# Why does ReactiveAssert.AreElementsEqual return false when the results it shows me are equal?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, system.reactive

I'm sure I'm missing something obvious here (failing equals comparisons are usually something simple), but I'm at a loss. I have a unit test with a single assert:

```
ReactiveAssert.AreElementsEqual(expected.ToList(), actual.Messages.ToList());
```

where expected is a `{Microsoft.Reactive.Testing.Recorded<System.Reactive.Notification<Services.Messaging.Interfaces.IMessage>>`

and actual is a

`{Microsoft.Reactive.Testing.MockObserver<Services.Messaging.Interfaces.IMessage>}`

Both are converted to `List<OnNext(Services.Messaging.Messages.RolloverMessage)>` objects and then compared. So the error message I get is:

> Expected: [OnNext(Services.Messaging.Messages.RolloverMessage)@1,
>   OnNext(Services.Messaging.Messages.RolloverMessage)@10000001,
>   OnNext(Services.Messaging.Messages.RolloverMessage)@20000001,
>   OnNext(Services.Messaging.Messages.RolloverMessage)@30000001,
>   OnNext(Services.Messaging.Messages.RolloverMessage)@40000001]
>
> Actual..: [OnNext(Services.Messaging.Messages.RolloverMessage)@1,
>   OnNext(Services.Messaging.Messages.RolloverMessage)@10000001,
>   OnNext(Services.Messaging.Messages.RolloverMessage)@20000001,
>   OnNext(Services.Messaging.Messages.RolloverMessage)@30000001,
>   OnNext(Services.Messaging.Messages.RolloverMessage)@40000001]
>
> Expected: True Actual:   False

Which is confusing and infuriating. Any suggestions? Is there any information I've left out which would be useful?

Comment: Chances are it's testing whether or not the two arguments reference the same list.

Comment: Does `RolloverMessage` override the default `Equals` method?

Comment: @Lee No, it uses the default.

Comment: The default implementation tests reference equality (assuming `RolloverMessage` is a class) so you need to override `Equals` (and ideally `GetHashCode`).

Comment: @Lee Thanks, I'll try that.

Comment: @Lee That did the trick. Feel free to write it up as an answer and I'll mark it as such.